# Binding in Mode OneTime unsuccessful

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need help with binding modes.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon,Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

If `Mode=OneTime` the icon never appears; Thread entered once.

But, if `Mode=OneWay` then the icon appears but the thread is started two times,

```
private ImageSource icon;
public ImageSource Icon
{
    get
    {
        if ((icon == null) )
        {
            var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                ImageSource source = cIcon.GetImage(fullPath);              
                Icon = source;              
            });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();                   
        }
        return icon;
    }
    set
    {
        if (icon != value)
            icon = value; OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
    }
}
```

This is part of ObservableCollection which is linked to Listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `OneTime`, the `get` gets called **once**, then you start the thread, and it returns null.

your `OneTime` is used up, the end.  One time is one time.  Not "one time, and then later if it changes, get it *one more time*"

Nothing is subequently listening for the property changed event that occurs later, since you told it to only get the thing once, and never listen to property changes.

The way your code is written, the thread will could start twice (or more), because you don't have anything to guard against it.  if the first thread hasn't finished before someone calls the getter again, you'll get another thread. Do you really need another thread to load that image? you might be better off using async/await instead of new threads.

Also, your setter is *always* firing OnPropertyChanged regardless of if the value changes, because

```
if (icon != value)
    icon = value; OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
```

is not the same thing as

```
if (icon != value)
{
    icon = value; 
    OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and catching missing brackets! SHGetFileInfo is really slow for network links so I think I need thread. Is there anything better than having before entering thread if(ExtractionStarted) return;else {ExtractionStarted=true;return;}